# How to add CSS in HTML if I have 2 Titles on LWC

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components, json, css, html5

I created 1 LWC, in which I have main Title & I wanted to add another Title in the same HTML page.

```
<template>
    <lightning-card variant="Narrow" icon-name="standard:timesheet" title="Raceway and Junction Box">
        <template for:each={newjbfloorlis} for:item="jbFloorLI" for:index="index" key={keyIndex}>
            {jbFloorLI.Installation_Activity__c} ***---- I wanted to add Another Title over here with the help of Css or any LWC Tag***
            <lightning-record-edit-form key={jbFloorLI.Id} object-api-name="DPR_Line_Items__c" class="dprLineItem">
                <lightning-layout multiple-rows>
                    <lightning-layout-item size="12" small-device-size="6" medium-device-size="4" large-device-size="2"
                        padding="around-small">
                        <lightning-input-field field-name="Project_Items__c" value={jbFloorLI.Project_Items__c}
                            variant="label-stacked" disabled="true">
                        </lightning-input-field>
</lightning-record-edit-form>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Right Now it is showing like this.
The Raceway & Junction Box is a title which should be Bold
[image]

pic no:2

[image]

Comment: Didnt understand the issue. Can you please explain what do you mean by `I wanted to add Another Title over here with the help of Css or any LWC Tag` , and do you just want to make `Raceway and Junction Box`  bold? or anything else?

Comment: @NagendraSingh: Raceway and Junction Box is already my title. below that {jbFloorLI.Installation_Activity__c} get data which I wanted to show as a title in bold. In pic no.2 ......... The Basket Tray Installation is fetched from {jbFloorLI.Installation_Activity__c}and it is a Title which needs to be bold

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want `{jbFloorLI.Installation_Activity__c}` to be in bold, you can easily go ahead and wrap it inside a `<div>` and add a `class` attribute to it.

Something like this.

```
<div class="slds-text-title_bold" key={jbFloorLI.Id}>{jbFloorLI.Installation_Activity__c}</div>
```

With icon:

```
<div class="slds-text-title_bold" icon key={jbFloorLI.Id}>
    <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:connected_apps" alternative-text="Connected" size="xx-small" title="xx-small size"></lightning-icon>
    {jbFloorLI.Installation_Activity__c}
</div>
```

Comment: yes it worked for me.

Comment: @narendra What if I wanted to add standard icon on the same div??? Can I add that?

Comment: Yes sure you can, I added an example for ICON too.

Comment: It works but there is no gap between Title and Icon.why??

Comment: That you can add some padding / margin and create gap